# Variable value not getting preserved when piping to another program

Tags: bash, pipe, zsh

I have a function called `directory_chooser` and it contains code to update a variable `serial` in it multiple times. Now this usually works fine, but now I'm piping that whole function to `column` and the value updated by the `directory_chooser` function does not get preserved.

Here's the line of code where the problem is occurring:

```
directory_chooser $1 | column -t -s $'\t'
```

If I do not pipe the function to `column`, the code works perfectly. However, piping to column causes the value of `serial` as updated by the `directory_chooser` to not be preserved. **I'm guessing that's because pipe commands are all executed in a subshell?**

Since I need to use the value of `serial` later in the script, it is important to me that the value of serial is preserved after the `directory_chooser` function increments it.

What could be the workaround for this? If you want to look at the whole code, you can look at it [here](https://github.com/AviusX/linux-navigator/blob/no-file-test/navigator.sh). I haven't been able to find any solution that fits a situation similar to mine. Will I have to rewrite the whole script?

I was originally trying to write the whole output of `directory_chooser` to a file and then pipe the whole file to `column` to achieve the same thing and everything was working fine, but I want a more elegant solution. Besides, writing to file every time the script runs causes it to become a lot slower than if I can simply pipe the whole function to `column`.

[Here's](https://github.com/AviusX/linux-navigator/blob/master/navigator.sh) the working version of the script where I was writing to a file. **You can also read another, shorter explanation of the issue [here](https://github.com/AviusX/linux-navigator/blob/master/TODO.txt).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Pipes spawn subshells and variables changed in a subshell don't change the parent's variables.

You can switch the pipe to [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), which will run `column` in a child process but leave `directory_chooser` in the parent.

```
directory_chooser "$1" > >(column -t -s $'\t')
```