# Modify global Variable in a Bash Function called with a Pipe

Tags: bash, environment-variables, pipe

I have the following pattern in a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

a="Default"

the_function() {
    echo "Something"
    a="Set By Function"
}
```

Just a function that alters the value of a global variable.

If I call it, it works as intented, the following call (also in the same script):

```bash
echo $a
the_function
echo $a
```

Prints the expected:

```
Default
Something
Set By Function
```

But if I call the function and pipe its output, the variable is not altered (outside of the function):

This call:

```bash
echo $a
the_function | tee my-log-file.log
echo $a
```

The output:

```
Default
Something
Default
```

What is the difference in environment between a function call and a function call that pipes the output?
And how can I pipe the output and still have the variable altered?

Comment: When you pipe, Bash creates two subprocesses: one subprocess to run what's on the left of the pipe, and another subprocess to run what's on the right of the pipe. The function _is_ actually changing the global variable, but it's the one that belongs to the subprocess, not the current process. As for your final question, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: To your question: You can't, because this would mean that a child process would affect the variables in its parent. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-functions-subprocesses) is an overview of the cases where a function is executed in a sub process. You have to redesign your program, so that you don't need this behaviour.

Comment: Also see [Variable value not getting preserved when piping to another program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60326574/4154375).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
the_function >( tee my-log-file.log )
```

to avoid the pipe.

Answer (score 3):

The man page for bash states:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

You cannot export variables to a parent shell. It is one of the properties of a subshell, that variable changes do not affect the parent.

On how to do that otherwise, try the following:

```
touch  my-log-file.log
tail -f my-log-file.log &
thetail=$!
the_function >> my-log-file.log
kill $thetail
```